# enable and disable of check box is not disabling the button

Tags: javascript

Below is my code :

According to my function when i check my check box the button has to be disabled and when i unchecked the check box button has to be enabled.

```
function assignDefect() {          
    var new_tc_arry = new Array();     
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('radSize1');    
    for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){   
        if(!checkbox[i].disabled && checkbox[i].checked){  
            var checkedbox = checkbox[i].value;            
            new_tc_arry.push(checkbox[i].value);    
            for(var i=0;i<new_tc_arry.length;i++){    
                console.log("new_tc_arry["+i+"] -->"+new_tc_arry[i]);    
                document.getElementById("OrphanbuttonId").disabled =true;   
            }    
        }    
        else {    
        document.getElementById("OrphanbuttonId").disabled=false;                                                                                      
        }   
}      

The above code is disabling my button when i check my last checkbox.
Its not working for 1st ,2nd..etc checkboxes.**
```

Comment: First set an alert to see if the function is triggered on checking the first two check boxes. Else check on the iterators

Comment: console.log("new_tc_arry["+i+"] -->"+new_tc_arry[i]);  ---> is printing the checked value on console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because even after you disable the button for the 1st, 2nd etc (excluding last check box) you continue your for loop. Basically, if your last checkbox is unchecked, the button will always be re-enabled. Try adding a break statement to your for loop:

```
function assignDefect() {          
    var new_tc_arry = new Array();     
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('radSize1');    
    for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){   
        if(!checkbox[i].disabled && checkbox[i].checked){  
            var checkedbox = checkbox[i].value;            
            new_tc_arry.push(checkbox[i].value);    
            for(var i=0;i<new_tc_arry.length;i++){    
                console.log("new_tc_arry["+i+"] -->"+new_tc_arry[i]);    
                document.getElementById("OrphanbuttonId").disabled =true;   
            }
            break; //<---------------------------------------CHANGE HERE    
        }    
        else {    
        document.getElementById("OrphanbuttonId").disabled=false;                                                                                      
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Pleasure :) would appreciate if you marked it as an answer if you are satisfied! Cheers!